# Analyze Coverage of Web Applications in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, vue.js, code-coverage, war, test-coverage

I have an application develloped with VueJS and executed in war with Tomcat. 
I need to get coverage of war, tests runnig separately with Selenium.
If any of you could point me in the right direction... it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this using [JaCoCo](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) requires two steps:

1) Add `jacocoagent` to your Apache Tomcat, that gathers coverage data and listens on a TCP port for requests to dump those data.

In `apache-tomcat/bin/setenv.bat` add Javaoptions:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:c:\\path\\to\\jacoco\\lib\\jacocoagent.jar=includes=your.classes.packages.*,classdumpdir=jacocoClasses,output=tcpserver
```

2) If you execute your tests using Maven, you can use the [jacoco-maven-plugin](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) for connecting to the TCP port opened by `jacocoagent` gathering the coverage data from your Apache Tomcat.

Incomplete example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>your/classes/packages/**</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-dump-report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>dump</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <address>localhost</address>
                <reset>true</reset>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>your/classes/packages/**</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Beware** that coverage data by JaCoCo are only applicable to exact thos `.class` files they have been collected with (identified by a check sum). Two compilations of a single `.java` file may result in `.class` files with different check sums. JaCoCo reports will thus declare it uncovered.

Comment: JaCoCo librairy is generator coverage for project java, In my case i need librairy for generate coverage from war. The war is deployed from framework Vue.js is used initially javascript, i don't have file .java or .class in war. tks

Comment: So you have deployed a pure JavaScript project to Tomcat? Then you are out of luck with JaCoCo, as you said. Maybe you should add [javascript] tag to your question too, or ask it again stating explicitly that you need JavaScript code coverage only as .war files normally contain Java Servlet applications.